# CSS Performance

Tags: css

Is there any performance difference between:

```
p {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

and omitting the final semicolon:

```
p {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So all your other css, html and server-side processing is so streamlined that you worry about browsers' ability to parse css down to a semi-colon?

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out what the difference was

Comment: I edited to clarify that semicolon bit.

Comment: @klausbyskov I doubt it but why not asking...

Comment: Sounds like a bet between coworkers

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close. The question isn’t vague or ambiguous at all. It would take a lot of work to answer it, because you’d have to figure out a way to profile CSS rendering performance in a few different browsers, but it’s very specific and answerable. (And I’d love for someone to actually figure out how to do the profiling. Pointless, but fascinating.)

Comment: You should also remove the `px` part when the units are 0, because in that case, units don't mean anything.

Comment: @JaZz because at best it would be a micro-optimization. I don't say that it's not a valid question, I'm just implying that such small details almost never impact performance, and therefore should not be the focus of your attention. If you want to performance tune your application I would start by looking at database access and caching of static data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is not, the browser doesn't care about the trailing semicolon, even in IE6.  The parser checks for it as a delimiter that's it.

If anything, since the browser is basically performing tokenization not much more complex than `.split(';')`, the second may be faster in a probably not measurable way simply because of the lack of an extra null token.  But...the difference would be infinitesimal, and you do **not** need to worry about it either way.

Comment: And more to the point, leaving out the final semicolon is a maintenance issue to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt it. But, of course, no one has ever measured such a thing independently!

Answer (score 1):

I think the main difference will be in the increased css file size. but even if your css file was too big it'll just increase by few bytes. so in short I think it is ok not to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

No, ";" is seperator.

I think we can't talk about performance in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually better off using a [CSS minifier](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+minify). In short, it will remove all of the unnecessary spaces and bloat (e.g., changing `#ffffff` to `#fff` where appropriate, removing comments, etc). Some of them will automatically remove the last semicolon in each block. Be aware this can cause issues, as @t-j-crowder mentioned, if you later add lines to the end of the block and forget to add back the semicolon!

Also, make sure you're using external CSS files where possible and store them on the same server/ [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). If you can, combine your external CSS files into one so you minimize the number of requests the browser has to make.

This will speed up the *download time* and give you the biggest bang for your buck in terms of optimization. If the browser caches the files, subsequent visits to the same page (or to different pages using the same stylesheets) will be faster.